# SMS email gateway remove "FRM" and "MSG" in header

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

When I send a email to SMS to my AT&T phone, it comes up as:

```
FRM:****@gmail.com
MSG: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem
ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
```

Is there a way to remove the "FRM: ..." and "MSG:" and only send the message contents? Maybe there is a workaround, to somehow exclude the "from" field in the email header so that it isn't displayed when it converts to sms?